# Passing pivot table data from laravel to VueJS component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Im adding VueJs Components to my Laravel App and im struggling with this question:

I have 2 models, Concessions and Brands, with a ManyToMany relationship like this:

Concession Model

```
  public function brands()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Brand');
  }
```

Brand Model

```
  public function concessions()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Concession');
  }
```

in the controller im fetching the data from all the Concessions and returning to the view like this:

```
public function concessions()
{
    $concessions = Concession::all();

    return view('MyConcessionsView', compact('concessions'));
}
```

on my Laravel View i can access to `$concessions[0]->brands` with no problem and everything is working fine.

So, im adding my Vue component, and i'm passing the prop $concessions to that component:

```
<concessions-map :con="{{ $concessions }}"></concessions-map>
```

On my Vue component im accepting the prop 'con' and i can display all the elements from that array. **BUT** i need access from each brand form each concession and when i try, for example, display `con[0].brands[0]` or even `con[0].brands` it gives me the error **Cannot read property 'brands' of undefined**".

I even pass this prop to State on Mounted() lifecycle method:

```
 mounted() {
    this.concessions = this.con;
}
```

and on Vue DevTools i have the array with 35 objects.. but i can access the property brands from each one.

Any advice?

Thanks (a lot) in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```xml
$concessions = Concession::with('brands')
```

This is what you need.

when you execute

```xml
$concessions[0]->brands
```

You are making a new request to the database.

Answer (score 0):

hi,
you can work with Axios is a better way so
-1 define a function in your concessions controller  to get every concessions with its brands

```
public function getConcessions(){
    $concessions= Concession::with('brands');
    return $concessions;
}
```

-2 define a route to fetch this data in your web.php
for example

```
Route::get('/concessions/getData','ConcessionController@getConcessions');
```

-3 fetch data with axios from your vuejs component

```
loadConcessions(){
             axios.get("/concessions/getData")
              .then(({data}) => {
              this.concessions = data.data

            });
```

and do not forget to add this function in your mounted methode

```
mounted() {
           this.loadConcessions()

        }
```

-4 now you can display the data fetched in your vuejs component

- in your case you do for example

  {{concessions.brands}}

and even you can read it as a loop with v-for for example read it in a table

```
<tr  v-for="concession in concessions.data" :key="concessions.id">
   <td class="text-center">{{concession.brands}}</td>
</tr>
```

so for each concession, it will display its brands